# Opencart - Add "Add to Wishlist" to Category pages

Tags: php, button, e-commerce, opencart

Trying to add the "add to Wishlist" to the coding so it will display on the Category pages.  So each product displayed in the category field will have its own separate "ADD TO WISHLIST" button.  I will also replicate this over to the search method as well since a great deal of my categories are actually searches.  The Site I am working on has a lot of similar products and are mainly visual so it would really come in handy.

The Current Code that I have in place for the ADD TO WISHLIST is (left out the CSS - no need to bore anyone!):

```
<a class="wish_add" href="<?php echo $add_to_wishlist[$j]['add']; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_to_wishlist; ?>" rel="nofollow"><span><?php echo $button_to_wishlist; ?>+ Favorites</span></a>
```

The Code for the entire page is (CATEGORY.TPL):

```
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div><!--[if lt IE 7]><br /><![endif]-->
    <?php if (!$categories && !$products) { ?>
    <div class="content"><?php echo $text_error; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
  if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']!='_route_=ketubahs'){
  ?>
    <!--<?php /* if ($categories) { */ ?> -->
    <?php if ($categories && $heading_title!="Scroll Down to View All Our Ketubahs on One Page") { ?>
    <table class="listC" cellspacing="7">
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($categories); $i = $i + 4) {
       $numpages=sizeof($products);
      ?>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) { ?>
        <td width="25%"><?php if (isset($categories[$j])) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $categories[$j]['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $categories[$j]['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $categories[$j]['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $categories[$j]['name']; ?>" style="margin-bottom: 3px;" /></a><br />
          <a href="<?php echo $categories[$j]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $categories[$j]['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <?php } 
                                                   }
    ?>
    <?php if ($products) { ?>
 <!-- <div class="sort"> -->
      <div class="sort" <?php if ($heading_title=="Scroll Down to View All Our Ketubahs on One Page") { echo "style='margin-top:-40px;'"; } ?> >
      <div class="div1">
        <select name="sort" onchange="location = this.value">
          <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
          <?php if (($sort . '-' . $order) == $sorts['value']) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="div2"><?php echo $text_sort; ?></div>
    </div>
    <table class="listC" cellspacing="7">
      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($products); $i = $i + 4) {
       $numpages=sizeof($products);
      ?>
      <tr>
        <?php for ($j = $i; $j < ($i + 4); $j++) { ?>
        <td width="25%">
<?php if (isset($products[$j])) { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $products[$j]['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $products[$j]['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?>" width="210px" height="210px" /></a><br /><Br />
          <div style="margin-top:-15px;"><a href="<?php echo $products[$j]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $products[$j]['name']; ?></a><br />
<?php       if($products[$j]['artist'] != 'Rosenthal, Gary' and $products[$j]['artist'] != 'Jessy Judaica' and !empty($products[$j]['artist'])){
            $artist_fname=substr($products[$j]['artist'],strpos($products[$j]['artist'],",")+1);
            $artist_lname=substr($products[$j]['artist'],0,strpos($products[$j]['artist'],","));
        $artist_fullname=trim($artist_fname)." ".trim($artist_lname);
        if (trim($products[$j]['artist'])=="Zeev") {
        $artist_fullname="Ze&#39;ev"; }
        if (trim($products[$j]['artist'])=="This is not a Ketubah") {
        $artist_fullname="This is not a Ketubah"; }
        $artistname=str_replace(' ','-',$artist_fullname);
        if (trim($artistname)=="Ze&#39;ev") {
        $artistname="Ze-ev"; }
        if (trim($artistname)=="This is not a Ketubah") {
        $artistname="This is not a Ketubah"; }
        $artist_path='meet-our-artists/'.strtolower($artistname);
 ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $artist_path; ?>"><span style="color:#FFF;font-weight:200;"><?php echo $artist_fullname; ?></span></a><br />
<?php } else { ?>
          <span style="color: #999; font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $products[$j]['model']; ?></span><br />
<?php } ?>
          <?php if ($display_price) { ?>
          <?php if (!$products[$j]['special']) { ?>
          <span style="color: #00d8ff; font-weight: bold;cursor:default;"><?php echo $products[$j]['price']; ?></span>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span style="color: #00d8ff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: line-through;"><?php echo $products[$j]['price']; ?></span> <span style="color: #FAA; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $products[$j]['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
</div>
          <?php } ?>
          <br />
          <?php if ($products[$j]['rating']) { ?>
          <img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars_<?php echo $products[$j]['rating'] . '.png'; ?>" alt="<?php echo $products[$j]['stars']; ?>" />
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>

        <a class="wish_add" href="<?php echo $add_to_wishlist[$j]['add']; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_to_wishlist; ?>" rel="nofollow"><span><?php echo $button_to_wishlist; ?>+ Favorites</span></a>
          <a class="cart_add" href="<?php echo $products[$j]['add']; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_add_to_cart; ?>" ><span><?php echo $button_add_to_cart; ?></span></a>

          </td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>

    </table>
    <div class="pagination" style="width:950px;text-align:right"><?php
    if (($numpages-$ii)>1) {
     echo "Displaying all ".($numpages-$ii)." items in this category.";
     } else {
     echo "Displaying 1 item in this category.";
     } ?></div>
         <?php } ?>



  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Any help would be amazing!

Cheers

AG

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.  There is a disabled feature in the controller that was preventing the button from going into production:

Located in Controller/category/category.php

```
$this->data['add_to_wishlist'] = HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=product/wishlist&p=' . $result['product_id'];
```

once enabled it feed that rest of the wish list code for Opencart allowing me to place the Wishlist and add to cart on each product within he category page:

located in view/category/category.php

```
<a href="<?php echo $add_to_wishlist; ?>" class="wish_add" rel="nofollow"><span><?php echo  $button_to_wishlist; ?>+ Favorites</span></a>
```